# Detect the input number of signs in python and use it in a loop for encryption

Tags: python

I am writing a very easy encryption program. I just shift the ASCII order number of a sign with a key. My code looks as following:

```
#Type in sign or text and key
clear_text = input("Text? ")
key = int(input("Key? "))

# saves ASCII order number of the sign
ord_number = ord(clear_text)

#shift ASCII odernumber with the key -> encryption
shift_ord_number = ord_number + key
key_ord_number = chr(shift_ord_number)
print(key_ord_number)
```

I want to advance this code by being able to type in a whole sentence. For this I somehow must detect how many signs the user has typed in. How would that be possible? And what loops would you recommend?

Comment: Just what do you mean by "sign" and "signs"?

Comment: I mean one symbol (character) as in one ASCII symbol, for example `A` or `>`.

Comment: Added the answer as per my understanding of the problem. Is that what you desire?

Comment: @anonymous You understood well. You and Scott Hunter get to the same solution with a different approach. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the string with the `for` loop and use your encryption logic with in the loop.

Making minimal changes to your original code, below is the sample code to achieve it:

```
clear_text = input("Text? ")
key = int(input("Key? "))

new_list = []
for c in clear_text:
    # saves ASCII order number of the sign
    ord_number = ord(c)

    #shift ASCII odernumber with the key -> encryption
    shift_ord_number = ord_number + key

    key_ord_number = chr(shift_ord_number)
    new_list.append(key_ord_number)

new_string = ''.join(new_list)
```

where `new_string` is the encrypted string.

Instead of `for` loop, you may also do *list comprehension* as:

```
new_string = ''.join(chr(ord(c) + key) for c in clear_text)
```

*Sample Example:*

```
>>> clear_text = 'This is the sample code'
>>> key = 3
>>> ''.join(chr(ord(c) + key) for c in clear_text)
'Wklv#lv#wkh#vdpsoh#frgh'  # <- value of "my_string"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a string for your sentence, from which you can extract individual characters to do your encryption on.  In fact, `clear_text` is already a string, but (presumably) since you only entered a single character, it is only 1 character long.

To get the length of a string, you can use `len(clear_text)`.  You can also iterate over the characters of a string using

```
for char in clear_text:
    ord_number = ord(char)
    shift_ord_number = ord_number + key
    key_ord_number = chr(shift_ord_number)
    print(key_ord_number)
```

Comment: Exactly, I want to use `clear_text[0], clear_text[1], ... , clear_text[n]`. What is n though?